# Issue with loading text file using numpy loadtxt

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, text-files

I am trying to load a text file which contains a set of arrays which looks like:

```
[ 90  91  92  93  94  95  96  97 100 101 102 103 157 158 159 160]
[ 58  59  60  61  62  63  76  77  78  79  80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87
  88  89  90  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99 100 102 103 104 105 108
 109 110 111 127 128 129 130 131 132 133 134 135 137 138 139 140 145 146
 147 148 171 172 173]
[  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17
  18  23  24  25  26  27  47  48  49  50  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58
  59  60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70  71  72  73  74  75  76
  77  78  79  80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89 165 166 167 168 169
 170 171 172 173]
```

I have tried using `test = np.loadtxt('filename.txt')` to load the text file but I keep getting this issue: `could not convert string to float: [`. The file does not contain any headers. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Into what data structure do you want this data to import?

Comment: Ideally into an array to allow me to do some calculations.

Comment: How many dimensions in this array? Does it need to be a numpy array?

Comment: I have 20 rows which represent each subject and each subject has different number of timepoints (columns).

Answer (score 0):

The following code will return a list of lists containing integers. This assumes that the data you have is all integers. If not, you can change the `map` call to convert to `float` instead:

```
import os.path as path

# Path to file.
path_to_data = path.join(path.dirname(path.realpath(__file__)),
                         'data.txt')
print(path_to_data)

# Read file contents.
with open(path_to_data) as file:
    data = file.read()
print(data)

# Now we need to parse it for square braces.
data = data.replace("\n", " ").replace("  ", " ").replace("  ", " ")
data = data.replace("[ ", "[").replace(" ]", "]")
print(data)

# Now we loop through the string looking for [ symbols.
data_list = []
start_index = 0
end_index = 0
while 0 <= data.find('[', start_index):
    start_index = data.find('[', start_index)
    if 0 <= start_index <= data.find(']', start_index):
        end_index = data.find(']', start_index)
        # Don't include the braces, actually: grab what's in-between.
        temp_str = data[start_index+1:end_index]

        # Now split into a list based on spaces.
        data_list.append(list(map(int, list(temp_str.split(" ")))))
        start_index = end_index

print(data_list)
```